# Disable opera map navigation

Tags: javascript, dictionary, navigation, opera

I've got a page setup where a map is displayed (ArcGIS Online) and a input box is presented. 
In Opera, for some reason, you're unable to type some characters in the input box. Instead, Opera navigates through the map on that `keypress`. For example, when typing the letter 'a', Opera moves the map to the left corner.

[The page with map is here](http://tpgrf.nl/testserver/alpha/topotrainer/nederland/)

After a lot of searching the only thing I could came up with, is cathing the keypress event and return false, like this:

> var cancelKeypress = true;
>
> document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
>       evt = evt || window.event;
>       cancelKeypress = /^(112|113|65|97)$/.test("" + evt.keyCode);
>       if (cancelKeypress) {
>           return false;
>       } };
>
> /* For Opera */ document.onkeypress = function(evt) {
>       if (cancelKeypress) {
>           return false;
>       } };

But for some reason, that doesn't do the trick. Secondly, I'm wondering if there isn't a nicer solution which hooks on to Opera and blocks all the map navigation at once, in stead of blocking every `keypress` by it's own.

I would be more then happy if someone could explain what Opera is doing different compared to other browsers, which makes the input box unusable. Hopefully that knowledge would lead to a sollution to the answer.

Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

This might only elaborate your description of the problem. Have you tried things like:

- [preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) / [isDefaultPrevented()](http://api.jquery.com/event.isDefaultPrevented/)
- [stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) / [isPropagationStopped()](http://api.jquery.com/event.isPropagationStopped/)
- [stopImmediatePropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/) / [isImmediatePropagationStopped()](http://api.jquery.com/event.isImmediatePropagationStopped/)

Comment: I could try that, but that won't be a Opera specific solution. Isn't there something right out-of-the-box for Opera that prevents there method of keypress=map navigation?